# How to type mdash in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, punctuation

How can I type the HTML `&mdash;` character into the title field of my `.bib` file?

Comment: doesn't the standard LaTeX way work? ---

Answer (score 2):

```
(HTML) &mdash; = (TeX) --- [3 minus signs from a keyboard)
```